# file_get_contents access denied from facebook

Tags: php

When I try to use `file_get_contents` in PHP version 5.3, I get the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/search?callback=jsonps&q=love_story&type=post) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/website.com/app/c/fb.php on line 22
```

I've tried some different PHP settings but it still failed.

Comment: OOT question: why using PHP 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this function.

```
public function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
        else return FALSE;
}
```

Prasad.

Comment: echo $this->curl_get_file_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/search?callback=jsonps&q=book&type=post"); return is blank.

Comment: oddly enough if I test your script on my server that is different it worked fine. and even more unusual than facebook site all worked fine as well.

Comment: I am getting the JSON data. Don't understand why this return blank for you. If it is not our coding fault it could be a PHP version issue.

Comment: please look at this: http://lh3.ggpht.com/iOw0k_RVzZVsZ6G6PChkWoU_YZQeUlvudsy_w2USleANAmgSGI_NEpf9AvXy1hjxGmLfUw=s96

Comment: jsonps is calback function event handle javascript, I have tried it worked fine in server first.

Comment: http://lh6.ggpht.com/DKnl0rf7tQ5e-FNSz6VcIJZe3xh3g8iVhIVw-0uWUPyuzIoDhGGmfLEnpFJO5Q_QXox9rw=s166

Answer (score 0):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) instead of `file_get_contents`.